# setQueryParameters isn't part of `'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-bigquery', version: '0.4.0'`

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm not sure which lib to include:

```
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-bigquery:v2-rev327-1.22.0'
```

or

```
compile group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-bigquery', version: '0.4.0'
```

I saw this [example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#bigquery_sync_query_java) on how to set a bigQ java client

However I want to inject the params into the bigQ query.

I thought to use this:

```
    List<QueryParameter> params =  new ArrayList<>();

    QueryParameter param = new QueryParameter();
    param.setName("country");
    param.setParameterValue(new QueryParameterValue().setValue(brandChangeDataUi.country));
    param.setParameterType(new QueryParameterType().setType("string"));
    params.add(param);

    param = new QueryParameter();
    param.setName("countryAbbr");
    param.setParameterValue(new QueryParameterValue().setValue(brandChangeDataUi.countryAbbr));
    param.setParameterType(new QueryParameterType().setType("string"));
    params.add(param);

    param = new QueryParameter();
    param.setName("brand");
    param.setParameterValue(new QueryParameterValue().setValue(brandChangeDataUi.country));
    param.setParameterType(new QueryParameterType().setType("string"));
    params.add(param);



    JobConfigurationQuery jobConfigurationQuery = new JobConfigurationQuery();
    jobConfigurationQuery.setQueryParameters(params);
    jobConfigurationQuery.setUseLegacySql(false);


    jobConfigurationQuery.setQuery( "select id,lng,lat,venue3.brand.value from waze_prod.venues_full.versioned.latest " +
                    "where (country = @country or country = @countryAbbr)";
```

but I wonder how come there is no official example with `setQueryParameters`.

It's not part of the lib here `compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-bigquery:v2-rev327-1.22.0'`

Should I use something else?

However I want to inject the parameters

Answer (score 0):

See [BigQuery API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/bigquery/v2) and its [JavaDoc](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/).